# Show label to a particular column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two labels in my screen where I calculate values and show up in my page below the gridview.

Is it possible to show the labels to a specific column index. There are my labels and I need to show them below column index of 4 & 5.

```
Label4.Text = sum2.ToString();
Label5.Text = sum1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of showing the sums in separate labels, you can show them in the footer of the GridView. 
This [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/displaying-summary-information-in-the-gridview-s-footer-vb) shows how to do this. Basically, you have to carry out the following steps:

- Set the [ShowFooter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showfooter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-property of the GridView to true.
- Handle the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and set the footer information in the event handler code.

Sample for the RowDataBound event handler:

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = sum1.ToString();
      e.Row.Cells[2].Text = sum2.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its like I have two gridviews in my page and each gridview has calculations in the footer. And I need to show gross total of both the gridviews in a label.

Comment: @Vicky: you could also use a Repeater (at least for one of the GridViews). This allows you to control the generated HTML much better. This way, you could create two footer rows in the FooterTemplate, apply a different style to them and show the gross total in the second row.